# What does the type "string * string" mean in F#?

Tags: f#

Tried searching everywhere. 
Looking at https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/Fake.IIS/IISHelper.fs#L64 with parameter `string * string`. 
Tried to instantiate in F# code and received error FS0010: Incomp
lete structured construct at or before this point in expression.

What in the world is this and how does on instantiate this?

Comment: Try typing `let foo = "bar", "baz";;` into F# Interactive, and see what it returns.

Comment: It's not very helpful to say "try reading a book or tutorial" without giving links. I'd recommend the https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/ website. Look at the "Series" list on the right and start reading them in order, starting with the "[Why use F#?](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/why-use-fsharp.html)" series. Once you get to the "[Understanding F# Types](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/types-intro/)" series, you'll find the explanation of the tuple syntax that was puzzling you.

Comment: Also, why has this question been downvoted so much? This is something that's hard to search for, so there's nothing wrong with asking a basic question like this on Stack Overflow. The OP specifically mentioned that he's been unsuccessful in searching; this is exactly the kind of question that *should* be asked, and it's disappointing that it's being downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: I too am suprised this is downvoted as much. Simple questions with simple answers have a place too. If this is a duplicate it should be closed as such otherwise I think this one is fine.

Comment: Maybe downvoted for reasons fixed in edits?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Is seems to me that right now your Q  a bit foggy and not very good for SO. I think better to ask this kind of questions in chats. I advise you to join to the [FSSF slack](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/). If you will have any problem with it - just ping me in the [SO chat F# room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f). Well, SO room is great place too, but much less more active so you may have problem with getting quick answers.

Comment: Just flagged glennsl's condescending comment that is likely to discourage  the poster to ask future questions as well as others that demonstrate interest in learning F#. The question is basic to anybody that is familiar with F#. Perhaps this person is trying to get familiar with this wonderful language and that's why they asked.

Comment: Trying to use F# to do some continuous integration. This have been resolved but more troubles with fake.deploy have appeared.

Answer (score 6):

`string*string` is a pair of two strings and is roughly equal to [`Tuple<string, string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx). `string*int*decimal` is then roughly equal to `Tuple<string, int, decimal>`.

You create an instance of `string*string` using the following expression `"first", "second"`. An instance of `string*int*decimal` is created like so `"1", 2, 3.0M`.

For more information on tuples see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/tuples

The rationale for this notation is easier to see if you consider that F# has an algebra for creating types; `*` create tuples and `|` creates unions.

```
// Tree is roughly equal to having an interface Tree 
//  with three implementations Empty, Leaf and Fork
type Tree<'T> =
  | Empty
  | Leaf  of 'T
  | Fork  of Tree<'T>*Tree<'T>
```

Having an algebra for type creation is very powerful as Scott Wlaschin demonstrates: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/ddd/